# Javacc - Eliminating choice conflict by using left factoring instead of lookahead

Tags: regex, parsing, compiler-construction, stringtokenizer, javacc

I am writing a JAVACC program for a simple language and I am running into 1 conflict which is fixable by using a LOOKAHEAD(2).Would I be able to overcome this issue by left-factoring the code rather than using a look-ahead and if not, why?

GRAMMAR

```
void expression() : {}
{
    simple_expression() (addition_or_substraction() | {})
}

void simple_expression() : {}
{
    <NUMBER>
    | <LBRAC> expression() <RBRAC> 
}

void condition() : {}
{
     simple_condition() (compare_condition() | {})
} 

void prime_condition() : {}
{
    expression_comparison()
    |<NOT_OPERATOR> condition()
    | LOOKAHEAD(2) <LBRAC> condition() <RBRAC> // Choice conflict for "("
}

void expression_comparison() : {}
{
    expression()
    (   
         <EQUAL> expression()
         <LESS_THAN> expression()
         <GREATER_THAN> expression()
    )
}

void compare_condition() : {}
{
    <AND> condition() | <OR> condition()
}
```

Comment: What is the final regex that you're considering factoring ?

Comment: @sln prime_condition

Comment: Yeah, I'd just use `(?(condition)yes_regex|no_regex)`

Comment: Put together a complete substitution rather than a series of function calls. Or, post the overall regex that would be used to parse your source. Then I can tell you what to do. To me it looks like an endless loop.

Comment: The premise of the question is wrong.  The LOOKAHEAD(2) does not fix the conflict.  It does shut off the warning.  See the FAQ regarding LOOKAHEADs and warnings.

Comment: Other than my quibble in the previous comment, it's an interesting question.  Have you tried left factoring?  If so did it work?  If not, what sort of trouble did you run in to?

Comment: I assume `simple_condition` and `prime_condition` should be one and the same nonterminal.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think that you can left-factor your way out of the problem.  I suspect (but haven't proved) that the language generated from `condition` does not have an LL(1) grammar.

Anyway, let's try left factoring.  Let's work on a simpler --but similar-- grammar that contains the essentials of your problem. Terminals are `number`, `=`, `[`, and `]`.

```
C --> EXP = EXP  | [ C ]
EXP --> number | [ EXP ]
```

Now, I'm not going to do more because you should do it your self.  I'm fairly sure this is a homework problem, so if I do it here, I will be depriving you of the educational opportunity of doing it your self, not to mention the fun.

The first step is to expand the first occurrence of `EXP` in `C`.  Be sure not to stop until your grammar is LL(1) or you are sure that this is a fruitless task.

Comment: BTW, if you find this or any other answer useful, be sure to cite the answers in your homework submission, so as to avoid academic dishonesty.